# Get-ADComputer save results as string array?

Tags: powershell

What is the output format of Get-ADComputer?  I'm trying to do something like this to take an inventory.

```
[string[]]$server_list = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property Name #   Select-Object Name
```

However, when I use $server_list in a foreach, I see the object curly brackets like so

```
foreach ($machine_name in $server_list) {
   "processing : $machine_name";
}
```

output:

@{Name=some-machine-name-123-here}

I just need the actual name value, how do i get that?

Comment: What do you like to do with the collected data? Usually you get an array of objects. If you really only want the names as strings you can pipe the output to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`

Comment: Pipe to `| ForEach-Object -MemberName 'Name'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Property Name` parameter is unnecessary, as `Get-ADComputer` always retrieves the `Name` property. (This doesn't select *only* the `Name` property, as you seem to have thought.)

Rather than `-Property Name`, append `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` to your `Get-ADComputer` command line.

Answer (score 0):

So, my query returned a different result. Thus you might need to do a little work on this.

Basically, `-Property` says that you want an object with a certain field. Select does more or less the same thing.

If you want to keep your existing solution, expand the property instead of selecting it. This is the best way to do that:

`[string[]]$server_list = (Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property Name).Name`

You returned @{} which is powershell's way of representing an object inside a string. In this case, an object that contains properties about your ADComputers, of which you chose to only include "Name". If you included additional properties, you would see a larger comma separated list of type=value.

You can actually remove `-Property Name`, however this will take longer to run, since you're filtering on the right. (Gathering a lot of data and THEN filtering it to only Name.)

Comment: Removing `-Property Name` won't make the command take longer to run. `Name` is one of the default properties that `Get-ADComputer` always retrieves.